# Android: Knowing which button is pressed for buttons that are created programatically

Tags: android, button

I am trying to do this:

Programatically create 4 buttons on a layout. Then, create an onclick listener for each of the button. Then, based on which button is pressed, will do some logic.

I have created a LinearLayout in my XML file and called it "layout".

So, my codes go something like this:

```
    layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

    //Create the array of buttons
    Button [] subjectButtons_BT = new Button[4];

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        subjectButtons_BT[i] = new Button(this);
        // Add the button to the layout
        layout.addView(subjectButtons_BT[i]);
        subjectButtons_BT[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
               // if it is the first button, do LOGIC1
               // if it is the second button, do LOGIC2 etc 
                }
        });
    }
```

So far, I have managed to create the 4 buttons and I can click on the buttons.
However, I do not know how to the logic in the setOnClickListener part.

I wanted to know which button is pressed. So, I tried using v.getId() but it always returns a -1.

Can someone advise if this is the right way to go? And if so, how to do the logic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options for identify which dynamic button is clicked.

```
 1) Set ID to the button and compare ID 
 2) Set Tag to the button if you have come more information about button
     and want to access it
```

1) You can set id to the button and in `onClick()` method you can get id by `button.getId()` method and you can compare ids and perform action according to click.

2) If you set tag then you have to get tag by calling `button.getTag()` method and by this way you can pass object with the button

Answer (score 0):

You can set the id of the buttons after you create them, and then check for that id within the OnClickListener

```
layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

//Create the array of buttons
Button [] subjectButtons_BT = new Button[4];

for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    subjectButtons_BT[i] = new Button(this);
    subjectButtons_BT[i].setId(i);
    // Add the button to the layout
    layout.addView(subjectButtons_BT[i]);
    subjectButtons_BT[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = v.getId();
                if (id == 0) {
                } else if (id == 1) {
                }
                //etc.
            }
    });
}
```